# How to test a python eval statement in UWSGI application's ini config?

Tags: django, uwsgi, newrelic

As far I can tell, my eval statement within a USWGI's app config isn't working/executing, but I cannot figure out how to test this.

- **OS:** Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy)
- **UWSGI:** 1.2.3-debian
- **Python:** 2.7

I'm actually trying to setup Newrelic's application monitoring with the following in my `app.ini` file (using the [application mounting method](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-and-uwsgi#application-mounting) for a Django app):

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/app-user/myapp/bin
wsgi-file = django.wsgi
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
pythonpath = /home/app-user/myapp/src
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/app/myapp.log
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
eval = import newrelic.agent, django.wsgi; newrelic.agent.initialize('/path/to/newrelic.ini'); application = newrelic.agent.wsgi_application()(django.wsgi.application)
```

My `newrelic.ini` conf:

```
log_file = /tmp/newrelic-python-agent.log
```

After restarting and making some requests to the app (which is up and running as per usual) the newrelic log_file is not even created, and there is nothing in the **uwsgi app log** or the **django log**, so I don't know how to tell what is happening in the eval.

I've tried putting outright syntactically incorrect stuff in the eval, but uwsgi still restarts successfully.

Is there a way to validate what's in the eval statement as executed by the uwsgi process?

Comment: please report the whole uWSGI config, what you are decribing is not the expected behaviour, as eval will trigger exit on error. Report uWSGI version too.

Comment: Thanks for the expected behaviour. I've tried writing to files within the eval, but it's completely ignoring the option. I've included version info too.

Comment: it is a debian package, so it is modular, have you loaded the python plugin ? btw have you tried running your project without newrelic ? I find a bit strange you got it working without loading the plugin (unless you installed uwsgi via pip overwriting the debian one)

Comment: oh, and personally i find more handy this approach instead of using their wrappers: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-integration#wsgi-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm late to the party, but your problem was that you had `wsgi-file` option that made `eval` useless. (Same goes for `module` option - this is the case I had.)

So, to make uWSGI wrap any WSGI application with a middleware, you just had to remove the offending options. I.e.:

```
; DON'T USE THIS: wsgi-file=myproject/wsgi.py
; NEITHER THIS: module=myproject.wsgi
eval=import myproject.wsgi, myfancymw; application = myfancymw.wrap(myproject.wsgi.application)
```

Comment: This saved a lot of hours I've wasted. Thank you good stranger

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like there is a lot going on here. You might want to open a ticket with newrelic at

https://support.newrelic.com so they can investigate what is happening in your setup.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the newrelic app is a red-herring, as if all is removed, the **eval** statement still doesn't execute.